# <a> Tag deforms the Nav style

Tags: html, css, optimization

So when i want to ref the about-us listing on the nav it ruins the nav design.

I also used the optimization tag cuz there is probably something wrong with the code and maybe it needs some fixing!
Also here is a picture on how it looks like: http://puu.sh/8PJDC.jpg
You can visit :http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xfFgc  as i uploaded the html and css
the problem is at the More tab on Nav the about us is HUGE!
NOTE: i didn't code everything!

Thanks,-Pain-

Comment: Hey. I suggest you put an example online, codepen.io is a good one.

Comment: put your mark up and style here. May be you have added style for `<li>` only, add styles for `li > a` also.

Comment: I did a codepen as @magicspon suggested
here it is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xfFgc
as you can see there is a prob in the more tab

Comment: Im going to try this @TechnoKnol :D

Comment: Nope i cant find whats wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this styles are applying to your `li > a`

```
ul li a {
line-height: 80px;
padding: 0 20px;
height: 80px;
color: #777;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
-o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
```

replace with appropriate style.

Comment: Uhmm I really appreciate your help :D but im so d..b that...Uhh let me explain to you what i did!
 " 
li > a { line-height: 80px;
padding: 0 20px;
height: 80px;
} "
 but ofc i changed the values

Comment: UPDATE: it seems to be something else that affects that. i removed the ul li a and the problem stills there

Comment: it's right, but you should add style to this `.dropOut ul li > a ` because if you apply style to `li>a` it will be applied to all `a` in whole page.

Comment: ow i see :D im going to try this too!

Comment: and don't remove `ul li a`, instead add style for specific path of element, as wrote above.